# Swift try multiple JSONDecoder classes to see which one works

Tags: swift, jsondecoder

I am parsing the response from an API which looks like this

```
{
 "success":true,
 "data":[some other JSON objects]
}
```

I currently have 2 possible Objects to map the `data` to, but may have more in future.

Each of my object classes conform to the protocol `ResponseDataType` and I am using the following code to attempt to decode the data.

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case success, data
}

let success: Bool
let data: [ResponseDataType]

required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    success = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .success)
    
    var newData:[ResponseDataType]
    do
    {
        newData = try container.decode([ObjectType1].self, forKey: .data)
    }
    catch
    {
        newData = try container.decode([ObjectType2].self, forKey: .data)
    }
    
    data = newData
}
```

This work fine and my data is decoded to either `ObjectType1` or `ObjectType2`.

When I add a third data type, i'm thinking I will need to change it to this

```
var newData:[ResponseDataType]
do
{
    newData = try container.decode([ObjectType1].self, forKey: .data)
}
catch
{
    do
    {
        newData = try container.decode([ObjectType2].self, forKey: .data)
    }
    catch
    {
        newData = try container.decode([ObjectType3].self, forKey: .data)
    }
}

data = newData
```

and keep nesting the do, try,catch blocks as I get more.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: A better way is using generics (`T : Decodable`), I guess you do know what type you are going to decode respectively.

Comment: Since you don't seem to use the error/no print, why not doing `try?`, that would save you a lot of nesting, but it's harder to debug (when/why should one fail): `if let type1 = try? container...ObjectType1...) { newData = type1 } else if let type2 = try? container...ObjectType2...) { newData = type1 } else if let ...`

Comment: That certainly looks neater already. Thanks

Comment: Can be seen there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319139/how-to-decode-an-array-of-values-whose-types-depend-on-a-tag

Comment: I saw that, and that uses a `switch` to see what the `tag` is, but I have no indication of the data type.