# How can I implement polymorphic decoding of JSON data in Swift 4?

Tags: json, swift, codable

I am attempting to render a view from data returned from an API endpoint. My JSON looks (roughly) like this:

```
{
  "sections": [
    {
      "title": "Featured",
      "section_layout_type": "featured_panels",
      "section_items": [
        {
          "item_type": "foo",
          "id": 3,
          "title": "Bisbee1",
          "audio_url": "http://example.com/foo1.mp3",
          "feature_image_url" : "http://example.com/feature1.jpg"
        },
        {
          "item_type": "bar",
          "id": 4,
          "title": "Mortar8",
          "video_url": "http://example.com/video.mp4",
          "director" : "John Smith",
          "feature_image_url" : "http://example.com/feature2.jpg"
        }
      ]
    }    
  ]
}
```

I have an object that represents how to layout a view in my UI. It looks like this:

```
public struct ViewLayoutSection : Codable {
    var title: String = ""
    var sectionLayoutType: String
    var sectionItems: [ViewLayoutSectionItemable] = []
}
```

`ViewLayoutSectionItemable` is a protocol that includes, among other things, a title and a URL to an image to use in the layout.

However, the `sectionItems` array is actually made up of different types. What I'd like to do is instantiate each section item as an instance of its own class.

How do I setup the `init(from decoder: Decoder)` method for the `ViewLayoutSection` to let me iterate over the items in that JSON array and create an instance of the proper class in each case?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/44441223/2976878

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to be judicious on the use of `Codable`. If you only want to decode a type from JSON and not encode it, conforming it to `Decodable` alone is enough. And since you have already discovered that you need to decode it manually (via a custom implementation of `init(from decoder: Decoder)`), the question becomes: what is the least painful way to do it?

First, the data model. Note that `ViewLayoutSectionItemable` and its adopters do not conform to `Decodable`:

```
enum ItemType: String, Decodable {
    case foo
    case bar
}

protocol ViewLayoutSectionItemable {
    var id: Int { get }
    var itemType: ItemType { get }
    var title: String { get set }
    var imageURL: URL { get set }
}

struct Foo: ViewLayoutSectionItemable {
    let id: Int
    let itemType: ItemType
    var title: String
    var imageURL: URL
    // Custom properties of Foo
    var audioURL: URL
}

struct Bar: ViewLayoutSectionItemable {
    let id: Int
    let itemType: ItemType
    var title: String
    var imageURL: URL
    // Custom properties of Bar
    var videoURL: URL
    var director: String
}
```

Next, here's how we will decode the JSON:

```
struct Sections: Decodable {
    var sections: [ViewLayoutSection]
}

struct ViewLayoutSection: Decodable {
    var title: String = ""
    var sectionLayoutType: String
    var sectionItems: [ViewLayoutSectionItemable] = []

    // This struct use snake_case to match the JSON so we don't have to provide a custom
    // CodingKeys enum. And since it's private, outside code will never see it
    private struct GenericItem: Decodable {
        let id: Int
        let item_type: ItemType
        var title: String
        var feature_image_url: URL
        // Custom properties of all possible types. Note that they are all optionals
        var audio_url: URL?
        var video_url: URL?
        var director: String?
    }

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
        case sectionLayoutType = "section_layout_type"
        case sectionItems = "section_items"
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container     = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        title             = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        sectionLayoutType = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .sectionLayoutType)
        sectionItems      = try container.decode([GenericItem].self, forKey: .sectionItems).map { item in
        switch item.item_type {
        case .foo:
            // It's OK to force unwrap here because we already
            // know what type the item object is
            return Foo(id: item.id, itemType: item.item_type, title: item.title, imageURL: item.feature_image_url, audioURL: item.audio_url!)
        case .bar:
            return Bar(id: item.id, itemType: item.item_type, title: item.title, imageURL: item.feature_image_url, videoURL: item.video_url!, director: item.director!)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let sections = try JSONDecoder().decode(Sections.self, from: json).sections
```

Comment: One big takeaway for me from this is that it'll probably be better to re-think how I'm setting up and using my API than to jam it through in this manner.

Comment: Unless your types are really _ONLY_ limited to `Foo` and `Bar`, which is very unlikely to remain true forever in my experience, this design is quickly going to get out of hand. The problem is this comment: `Custom properties of all possible types`... what if you need to add _many_ new types later on? Or many different properties are possible on each type? `GenericItem` will quickly get huge...! This isn't good... Wherever possible, strive to shift logic to the polymorphic objects and keep the factory/intermediary objects small.

Comment: Be cautious about the statement "it's OK to force unwrap here because we already know what type the item object is". You know what type the item object _should_ be, but if the input JSON is malformed and missing one of those keys, that bad input data will crash the app.

Answer (score 8):

Polymorphic design is a good thing: many design patterns exhibit polymorphism to make the overall system more flexible and extensible.

Unfortunately, `Codable` doesn't have "built in" support for polymorphism, at least not yet....  there's also discussion about whether [this is actually a feature or a bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5331).

Fortunately, you can pretty easily create polymorphic objects using an `enum` as an intermediate "wrapper."

First, I'd recommend declaring `itemType` as a `static` property, instead of an instance property, to make switching on it easier later. Thereby, your protocol and polymorphic types would look like this:

```
import Foundation

public protocol ViewLayoutSectionItemable: Decodable {
  static var itemType: String { get }

  var id: Int { get }
  var title: String { get set }
  var imageURL: URL { get set }
}

public struct Foo: ViewLayoutSectionItemable {
  
  // ViewLayoutSectionItemable Properties
  public static var itemType: String { return "foo" }
  
  public let id: Int
  public var title: String
  public var imageURL: URL
  
  // Foo Properties
  public var audioURL: URL
}

public struct Bar: ViewLayoutSectionItemable {
  
  // ViewLayoutSectionItemable Properties
  public static var itemType: String { return "bar" }
  
  public let id: Int
  public var title: String
  public var imageURL: URL
  
  // Bar Properties
  public var director: String
  public var videoURL: URL
}
```

Next, create an enum for the "wrapper":

```
public enum ItemableWrapper: Decodable {
  
  // 1. Keys
  fileprivate enum Keys: String, CodingKey {
    case itemType = "item_type"
    case sections
    case sectionItems = "section_items"
  }
  
  // 2. Cases
  case foo(Foo)
  case bar(Bar)
  
  // 3. Computed Properties
  public var item: ViewLayoutSectionItemable {
    switch self {
    case .foo(let item): return item
    case .bar(let item): return item
    }
  }
  
  // 4. Static Methods
  public static func items(from decoder: Decoder) -> [ViewLayoutSectionItemable] {
    guard let container = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: Keys.self),
      var sectionItems = try? container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .sectionItems) else {
        return []
    }
    var items: [ViewLayoutSectionItemable] = []
    while !sectionItems.isAtEnd {
      guard let wrapper = try? sectionItems.decode(ItemableWrapper.self) else { continue }
      items.append(wrapper.item)
    }
    return items
  }
  
  // 5. Decodable
  public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Keys.self)
    let itemType = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: Keys.itemType)
    switch itemType {
    case Foo.itemType:  self = .foo(try Foo(from: decoder))
    case Bar.itemType:  self = .bar(try Bar(from: decoder))
    default:
      throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: .itemType,
                                             in: container,
                                             debugDescription: "Unhandled item type: \(itemType)")
    }
  }
}
```

Here's what the above does:

1. You declare `Keys` that are relevant to the response's structure. In your given API, you're interested in `sections` and `sectionItems`. You also need to know which key represents the type, which you declare here as `itemType`.
2. You then explicitly list *every possible* case: this violates the [Open Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle), but this is "okay" to do as it's acting as a "factory" for creating items....

   Essentially, you'll only have this *ONCE* throughout your entire app, just right here.
3. You declare a computed property for `item`: this way, you can unwrap the underlying `ViewLayoutSectionItemable` *without* needing to care about the actual `case`.
4. This is the heart of the "wrapper" factory: you declare `items(from:)` as a `static` method that's capable of returning `[ViewLayoutSectionItemable]`, which is exactly what you want to do: pass in a `Decoder` and get back an array containing polymorphic types! This is the method you'll actually use instead of decoding `Foo`, `Bar` or any other polymorphic arrays of these types directly.
5. Lastly, you must make `ItemableWrapper` implement  the `Decodable` method. The trick here is that `ItemWrapper` *always* decodes an `ItemWrapper`: thereby, this works how `Decodable` is expecting.

As it's an `enum`, however, it's allowed to have associated types, which is exactly what you do for each case. Hence, you can indirectly create polymorphic types!

Since you've done all the heavy lifting within `ItemWrapper`, it's *very* easy to now go from a `Decoder` to an `[ViewLayoutSectionItemable], which you'd do simply like this:

```
let decoder = ... // however you created it
let items = ItemableWrapper.items(from: decoder)
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement your solution for a JsonAPI type response. I do have a simple question, though... how do you create your decoder?? JsonDecoder doesn't seem to have a method that returns one.

Comment: You _don't_ create an instance of `Decoder`. Instead, `JSONDecoder` creates one internally whenever you call `try jsonDecoder.decode(...)`. See this tutorial for help: https://www.raywenderlich.com/172145/encoding-decoding-and-serialization-in-swift-4

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm starting to get the hang of it. Your answer helped me a lot and I feel it should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

A simpler version of @CodeDifferent's response, which addresses @JRG-Developer's comment. There is no need to rethink your JSON API; this is a common scenario. For each new `ViewLayoutSectionItem` you create, you only need to add one case and one line of code to the `PartiallyDecodedItem.ItemKind` enum and `PartiallyDecodedItem.init(from:)` method respectively.

This is not only the least amount of code compared to the accepted answer, it is more performant. In @CodeDifferent's option, you are required to initialize 2 arrays with 2 different representations of the data to get your array of `ViewLayoutSectionItem`s. In this option, you still need to initialize 2 arrays, but get to only have one representation of the data by taking advantage of copy-on-write semantics.

Also note that it is not necessary to include `ItemType` in the protocol or the adopting structs (it doesn't make sense to include a string describing what type a type is in a statically typed language).

```swift
protocol ViewLayoutSectionItem {
    var id: Int { get }
    var title: String { get }
    var imageURL: URL { get }
}

struct Foo: ViewLayoutSectionItem {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let imageURL: URL

    let audioURL: URL
}

struct Bar: ViewLayoutSectionItem {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let imageURL: URL

    let videoURL: URL
    let director: String
}

private struct PartiallyDecodedItem: Decodable {
    enum ItemKind: String, Decodable {
        case foo, bar
    }
    let kind: Kind
    let item: ViewLayoutSectionItem

    private enum DecodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case kind = "itemType"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: DecodingKeys.self)
        self.kind = try container.decode(Kind.self, forKey: .kind)
        self.item = try {
            switch kind {
            case .foo: return try Foo(from: decoder)
            case .number: return try Bar(from: decoder)
        }()
    }
}

struct ViewLayoutSection: Decodable {
    let title: String
    let sectionLayoutType: String
    let sectionItems: [ViewLayoutSectionItem]

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        self.sectionLayoutType = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .sectionLayoutType)
        self.sectionItems = try container.decode([PartiallyDecodedItem].self, forKey: .sectionItems)
            .map { $0.item }
    }
}
```

To handle the snake case -> camel case conversion, rather than manually type out all of the keys, you can simply set a property on `JSONDecoder`

```swift
struct Sections: Decodable {
    let sections: [ViewLayoutSection]
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
let sections = try decode(Sections.self, from: json)
    .sections
```

Comment: I think you meant to name the enum `Kind` and not `ItemKind`.

Comment: This is definitely the simplest of the answers so far while making it easy to add future items. I edited the answer for better compilation and that makes Frankie's comment obsolete.

Comment: There is something wrong in `PartiallyDecodedItem.init` – a bracket is missing plus I get "Constant 'self.item' used before being initialized" from the compiler. What am I missing (swift 5)?

Answer (score 1):

I have written a [blog post](https://lostmoa.com/blog/BringingPolymorphismToCodable/) about this exact problem.

In summary. I suggest defining an extension on `Decoder`

```swift
extension Decoder {
  func decode<ExpectedType>(_ expectedType: ExpectedType.Type) throws -> ExpectedType {
    let container = try self.container(keyedBy: PolymorphicMetaContainerKeys.self)
    let typeID = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .itemType)
     
    guard let types = self.userInfo[.polymorphicTypes] as? [Polymorphic.Type] else {
      throw PolymorphicCodableError.missingPolymorphicTypes
    }
     
    let matchingType = types.first { type in
      type.id == typeID
    }
     
    guard let matchingType = matchingType else {
      throw PolymorphicCodableError.unableToFindPolymorphicType(typeID)
    }
     
    let decoded = try matchingType.init(from: self)
     
    guard let decoded = decoded as? ExpectedType else {
      throw PolymorphicCodableError.unableToCast(
        decoded: decoded,
        into: String(describing: ExpectedType.self)
      )
    }
    return decoded
  }
}
```

Then adding the possible polymorphic types to the `Decoder` instance:

```swift
var decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.userInfo[.polymorphicTypes] = [
  Snake.self,
  Dog.self
]
```

If you have nested polymeric values you can write a property wrapper to that calls this decode method so that you do not need to define custom `init(from:)`.

Comment: I have implemented the blog post code yet the decoder never seems to attempt to decide the polymorphic property wrapped values. Could you show some working code and JSON file so I can trace the issue a bit better?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small [utility package](https://github.com/abdalaliii/Unboxing.git) that resolve this exact problem.

It was built around a configuration type that has variants for the decodable type defines the type information `discriminator`.

```swift
enum DrinkFamily: String, ClassFamily {
    case drink = "drink"
    case beer = "beer"

    static var discriminator: Discriminator = .type
    
    typealias BaseType = Drink

    func getType() -> Drink.Type {
        switch self {
        case .beer:
            return Beer.self
        case .drink:
            return Drink.self
        }
    }
}
```

Later in your collection overload the init method to use our `KeyedDecodingContainer` extension.

```swift
class Bar: Decodable {
    let drinks: [Drink]

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case drinks
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        drinks = try container.decodeHeterogeneousArray(OfFamily: DrinkFamily.self, forKey: .drinks)
    }
}
```