# Protocol extending Encodable (or Codable) does not conform to it

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, codable

I have 2 protocols, `Filters` and `Parameters`, both of which extend `Encodable`

```
protocol Filters: Encodable {
    var page: Int { get }
}

protocol Parameters: Encodable {
    var type: String { get }
    var filters: Filters { get }
}
```

I create structs conforming to these protocols, thusly…

```
struct BankAccountFilters: Filters {
    var page: Int
    var isWithdrawal: Bool
}

struct BankAccountParamters: Parameters {
    let type: String = "Bank"
    var filters: Filters
}

let baf = BankAccountFilters(page: 1, isWithdrawal: true)
let bap = BankAccountParamters(filters: baf)
```

Which fails because…

> error: type 'BankAccountParamters' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'
>
> note: cannot automatically synthesize 'Encodable' because 'Filters' does not conform to 'Encodable'

`Filters` clearly *does* conform to `Encodable` (at least it seems that way to me). Is there a way around this?

Comment: This looks like the same problem as in [Protocol doesn't conform to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33112559): A protocol does *not* conform to itself (or to any protocol that it inherits from).

Comment: It says in the docs that you are required to implement encode(to:): https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/encodable

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As discussed in [Protocol doesn't conform to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself), a protocol does not conform to itself, or to
a protocol that it inherits from. In your case, `Filters` does *not* conform to `Encodable`.

A possible solution is to make `struct BankAccountParamters` and
`protocol Parameters` generic:

```
protocol Filters: Encodable {
    var page: Int { get }
}

protocol Parameters: Encodable {
    associatedtype T: Filters
    var type: String { get }
    var filters: T { get }
}

struct BankAccountFilters: Filters {
    var page: Int
    var isWithdrawal: Bool
}

struct BankAccountParamters<T: Filters>: Parameters {
    let type: String = "Bank"
    var filters: T
}
```

Now `var filters` has type `T`, which conforms to `Filters` and consequently, to `Encodable`.

This compiles and produces the expected result:

```
let baf = BankAccountFilters(page: 1, isWithdrawal: true)
let bap = BankAccountParamters(filters: baf)

let data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(bap)
print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
// {"type":"Bank","filters":{"isWithdrawal":true,"page":1}}
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have protocol reference in the struct as the compiler will not be able to know the type at the time of encoding. Here is the bug reported [SR-5853](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5853?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Achangehistory-tabpanel).

What you can do is create a type erasure for your protocol and use the erasure in place of protocol.

Something like this:

> Update: As @MartinR answered there is no need of type erasure here.

```
protocol Filters: Encodable {
    var page: Int { get }
}

protocol Parameters: Encodable {
    associatedtype T: Filters
    var type: String { get }
    var filters: T { get }
}

struct BankAccountFilters: Filters {
    var page: Int
    var isWithdrawal: Bool
}

struct BankAccountParamters<T: Filters>: Parameters {
    let type: String = "Bank"
    var filters: T
}

let baf = BankAccountFilters(page: 1, isWithdrawal: true)
let bap = BankAccountParamters(filters: baf)

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
let data = try! encoder.encode(bap)
print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
```

Here you will get the output:

```
{"type":"Bank","filters":{"isWithdrawal":true,"page":1}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. It's close, but is missing `isWithdrawal` from the final output. I clearly need to read up on type erasure

Comment: You, Sir, are a genius! Thank you!

Comment: There is no need to use `AnyFilters` here. Please, check @MartinR 's answer.

Answer (score 1):

To get what you want without using generics, because of the multiple problems that come with using generics all over your code, you can provide your own implementation of `encode` method for the struct `BankAccountParameters`.

```swift
extension BankAccountParamters {
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case type, filters
  }

  func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(type, forKey: .type)
    if let bankAccountFilters = filters as? BankAccountFilters {
      try container.encode(bankAccountFilters, forKey: .filters)
    } else {
      assertionFailure("Type conforming to Filters is not encoded properly")
  }
}
```

This way, your type need not have generic constraints. But the flip side is that you have to ensure that all types which you conform to `Filters` in the future are encoded properly, that is where the `assertionFailure` on the else block might help.

Similarly, if you are decoding the `BankAccountParameters` struct, you have to provide your custom implmentation of `init(from: Decoder)`.