# In Swift why would a Struct/Class with stored property of type Protocol won't conform to Codable by default?

Tags: ios, swift

Below code compiles fine (Swift 5.0+)

```
import Foundation

protocol PriceType: Codable {
    var value: Double {get set}
    var currency: String {get set}
}

struct Price: PriceType {
    var value: Double
    var currency: String
}

struct Quantity: Codable {
    var value: Double
    var unit : String
}

struct Commodity: Codable {
    var price: Price
    var quantity: Quantity
}
```

The moment I change the definition of Commodity to below, the code doesn't compile.

```
struct Commodity: Codable {
    var price: PriceType
    var quantity: Quantity
}
```

The only change I made is that I made price property of the type PriceType.

I get below error

error: 019 - Codeable v2.xcplaygroundpage:20:8: error: type 'Commodity' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'
struct Commodity: Codable {
^

019 - Codeable v2.xcplaygroundpage:21:9: note: cannot automatically synthesize 'Decodable' because 'PriceType' does not conform to 'Decodable'
var price: PriceType
^

error: 019 - Codeable v2.xcplaygroundpage:20:8: error: type 'Commodity' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'
struct Commodity: Codable {
^

019 - Codeable v2.xcplaygroundpage:21:9: note: cannot automatically synthesize 'Encodable' because 'PriceType' does not conform to 'Encodable'
var price: PriceType

As per [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)

> The simplest way to make a type codable is to declare its properties
> using types that are already Codable. These types include standard
> library types like String, Int, and Double; and Foundation types like
> Date, Data, and URL. Any type whose properties are codable
> automatically conforms to Codable just by declaring that conformance.

Since PriceType conform to Codable as its two properties i.e. value and currency are by default Codable then **why code fails to compile** if I made the price property of type PriceType (protocol) instead of Price (struct)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protocols do not conform to themselfs or protocols they inherit, see: [Protocol extending Encodable (or Codable) does not conform to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50346052/protocol-extending-encodable-or-codable-does-not-conform-to-it). This won't be fixed, see: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5853?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Achangehistory-tabpanel

I think what you actually want is something like this:

```
struct Commodity<T: PriceType>: Codable {
    var price: T
    var quantity: Quantity
}
```