# How to use JSONDecoder with inheritance / protocols?

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, codable

Say I have a single array of `employees` and `employers` mixed together in a JSON. Both are inheriting from `Person`. What's the right way to handle it in JSONDecoder? Something like wouldn't work since we can't cast it back to a subclass:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let persons = try! decoder.decode([Person].self, for: jsonData)
```

And another point: can we use protocols instead of super classes here?

This is how my example JSON looks like:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "type": "employee",
    "employee_name": "xy"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "type": "employer",
    "employer_name": "xz"
}
]
```

Comment: Related: [Encode/Decode Array of Types conforming to protocol with JSONEncoder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44441223/2976878)

Answer (score 0):

First of all lets transform your json in a `Data` value

```
let data = """
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "employee",
        "employee_name": "xy"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "type": "employer",
        "employer_name": "xz"
    }
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!
```

> Important: Replace the "!" with a safer unwrapping method

### Model

Now we need a model value to mach the element in your JSON

```
struct ResponseElement:Codable {
    let id: Int
    let type: Type
    let employeeName: String?
    let employerName: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, type, employeeName = "employee_name", employerName = "employer_name"
    }

    enum `Type`:String, Codable {
        case employee, employer
    }
}
```

> As you can see `employeeName` and `employerName` are **optionals**, so this struct will be able to hold every element of your JSON (`Employers` and `Employee`).

### Person and its subclasses

Assuming you have a class `Person` like this

```
class Person {
    let id: Int
    let name:String

    init(id:Int, name:String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

You'll need to create the `Employee` and `Empolyer` subclasses like these

```
class Employee:Person {
    init?(responseElement:ResponseElement) {
        guard let name = responseElement.employeeName, responseElement.type == .employee else { return nil }
        super.init(id: responseElement.id, name: name)
    }
}
class Employer:Person {
    init?(responseElement:ResponseElement) {
        guard let name = responseElement.employerName, responseElement.type == .employer else { return nil }
        super.init(id: responseElement.id, name: name)
    }
}
```

> Please note that an `Employee` has a failable initializer that will try to create an `Employee` starting `ResponseElement`. Same for `Employer`.

### Lets decode!

```
do {
    let elements = try JSONDecoder().decode([ResponseElement].self, from: data)
    let employees = elements.filter { $0.type == .employee }.flatMap(Employee.init)
    let employers = elements.filter { $0.type == .employer }.flatMap(Employer.init)

    print(employees.count)
    print(employers.count)
} catch {
    print("Something bad has happened :\(error)")
}
```

Comment: hey Luca thanks for your solution. It would definitely work, but the ResponseElement seems to have too much of a knowledge of other model classes. Having only 2 models is not that of an issue, but having 5-10 models each having 5-10 fields would lead to a boilerplate code, IMO. See my answer for an interesting solution I've found on Github.