# Swift 4 Codable in protocol with enum property

Tags: swift, enums, swift4, codable

I have this protocol,

```
protocol PaginableItem {
   var resultType: ResultType { get set }
}
```

with a single property of an enum type,

```
enum ResultType: String, Codable {
   case photo = "PHOTO"
   case baseItem = "BASEITEM"
   case new = "NEW"
}
```

I also have 3 different structs and classes with conforms to `PaginableItem` and a class with some `PaginableItems`,

```
final class TimelineModel: Codable {
   let stream: String
   let participants: String
   let header1: PaginableList
   let header2: PaginableList
   let items: PaginableList
}

final class PaginableList: Codable {
   let data: [PaginableItem]
   let pagination: Pagination
}
```

I'm trying to cache `TimelineModel` using Swift 4 `Codable`, but I'm not sure the best way to do that. Xcode is complaining about `PaginableItem` not conforming to `Codable`.

It is mandatory to implement `init(from decoder: Decoder) throws` and `encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws` in `ResultType`?

Must `PaginableItem` implement `Codable` also?

Comment: Can you add the declaration for the `Pagination` item in `PaginableList`

Answer (score 4):

`PaginableItem` can't conform to `Codable` is because Swift protocols can't conform to themselves.

**Source:**

[Protocol doesn't conform to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself/43408193#43408193)

[Encode/Decode Array of Types conforming to protocol with JSONEncoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44441223/encode-decode-array-of-types-conforming-to-protocol-with-jsonencoder)

Following the second link above, if you want to encode/decode a `PaginableItem` you have to type erase them in an `AnyPaginableItem` class/struct and make that conform to `Encodable`/`Decodable`. I've done it like so:

```
protocol PaginableItem {
    var resultType: ResultType { get set }
}

class AnyPaginableItem: Codable {
    var resultType: ResultType

    init(resultType: ResultType) {
        self.resultType = resultType
    }
}

enum ResultType: String, Codable {
    case photo = "PHOTO"
    case baseItem = "BASEITEM"
    case new = "NEW"
}

struct ContainsPaginableItem: Codable {
    let paginableItem: AnyPaginableItem
}

let paginableItem = AnyPaginableItem(resultType: .photo)
let itemToEncode = ContainsPaginableItem(paginableItem: paginableItem)

let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(itemToEncode)
let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
```

This example only encodes the properties that can be declared in `PaginableItem`, which I assume is all you need.

If you need to encode ALL of the properties of the type conforming to `PaginableItem` there's a longer solution in the second link above that you can adopt.

Comment: The "longer solution" from the second link works perfect! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

> Must PaginableItem implement Codable also?

Absolutely! By making sure PaginableItem conforms to Codable, you maintain overall conformance to Codable for PaginableList.

I notice you had ResultType conform to Codable. However what happens if PaginableItem adds another object which does not - could be the danger.

Comment: I added the protocol `Codable` to `PaginableItem` but Xcode crashes when trying to encode the main `TimelineModel`:

`fatal error: Array<PaginableItem> does not conform to Encodable because PaginableItem does not conform to Encodable.`

Comment: Something you might want to try is to break up the conformance to Encodable/Decodable protocols- instead of conforming to Codable for the whole thing, create an extension for Encodable & another for Decodable

Comment: class Item: PaginableItem {
    let resultType: ResultType
    init(resultType: ResultType) {
        self.resultType = resultType
    }
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    //...
    }
}
extension Item: Encodable {
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(resultType, forKey: .resultType)
    }
}

Comment: not for protocols, but for classes/structs they can.

Comment: is it possible to alter PaginableItem to be a struct, then allow it to conform?