# Decode (JSON) subclassed array returns baseclass when using dictionary of types

Tags: arrays, swift, inheritance, decode

I was following along [this guide](https://medium.com/tsengineering/swift-4-0-codable-decoding-subclasses-inherited-classes-heterogeneous-arrays-ee3e180eb556) to decode my array of types, and when using that code directly, it works.

In case the link does not work in the future, here's what it looks like:

```
//JSON
var drinks = """
{
    "drinks": [
        {
            "type": "water",
            "description": "All natural"
        },
        {
            "type": "orange_juice",
            "description": "Best drank with breakfast"
        },
        {
            "type": "beer",
            "description": "An alcoholic beverage, best drunk on fridays after work",
            "alcohol_content": "5%"
        }
    ]
}
"""


    ...


    class Drink: Decodable {
        var type: String
        var description: String

        private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case type
            case description
        }
    }

    class Beer: Drink {
        var alcohol_content: String

        private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case alcohol_content
        }

        required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            self.alcohol_content = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .alcohol_content)
            try super.init(from: decoder)
        }
    }

    struct Drinks: Decodable {
        let drinks: [Drink]

        enum DrinksKey: CodingKey {
            case drinks
        }

        enum DrinkTypeKey: CodingKey {
            case type
        }

        enum DrinkTypes: String, Decodable {
            case water = "water"
            case orangeJuice = "orange_juice"
            case beer = "beer"
        }

        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: DrinksKey.self)
            var drinksArrayForType = try container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: DrinksKey.drinks)
            var drinks = [Drink]()

            var drinksArray = drinksArrayForType
            while(!drinksArrayForType.isAtEnd)
            {
                let drink = try drinksArrayForType.nestedContainer(keyedBy: DrinkTypeKey.self)
                let type = try drink.decode(DrinkTypes.self, forKey: DrinkTypeKey.type)

                switch type {
                case .water, .orangeJuice:
                    print("found drink")
                    drinks.append(try drinksArray.decode(Drink.self))
                case .beer:
                    print("found beer")
                    drinks.append(try drinksArray.decode(Beer.self))
                }
            }
            self.drinks = drinks
        }
    }
```

This code works, and when printing the class type after returning from the function, it prints an array of items with 'Drink', 'Drink' and '**Beer**' as expected. However, I wanted to make it more flexible, so instead of a switch/case, I wanted to insert the types in a dictionary and decode through there.

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var drinkDictionary: [String : Drink.Type] = [String : Drink.Type]()
        drinkDictionary["water"] = Drink.self
        drinkDictionary["orange_juice"] = Drink.self
        drinkDictionary["beer"] = Beer.self

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: DrinksKey.self)
        var drinksArrayForType = try container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: DrinksKey.drinks)
        var drinks = [Drink]()

        var drinksArray = drinksArrayForType
        while(!drinksArrayForType.isAtEnd)
        {
            let drink = try drinksArrayForType.nestedContainer(keyedBy: DrinkTypeKey.self)
            let type = try drink.decode(DrinkTypes.self, forKey: DrinkTypeKey.type)

           let view = try drinksArray.decode(drinkDictionary[type.rawValue]!.self)
            drinks.append(view)

        }
        self.drinks = drinks
    }
```

This is the (simplified) updated code that I would like to use. However, when running this code, the printed results are 'Drink', 'Drink' and '**Drink**'. So basically it's ignoring that it's a subclassed type when decoding, skipping the 'Beer' init altogether. Is it not supposed to work this way or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This is a [bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5928) that'll be fixed in Swift 4.1. Until fixed, you could workaround this problem by creating a wrapper type that calls `.init` on the metatype, rather than attempting to pass it into a `decode(_:)` method, as shown [in the second part of my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44473156/2976878). Or you could store closures as the values of your dictionary that take an (`inout`) unkeyed container argument and returns the decoded instance, but that doesn't seem as elegant.

Comment: Alright, I ended up going with the first method, wrap and call init, that'll work for now. Thanks