# How can a JSON array listing different objects be decoded into multiple structs using Swift's JSONDecoder?

Tags: json, swift, swift4, codable, decodable

Using this JSON object as an example:

```
{
  data: [
    {
      type: "animal"
      name: "dog"
      consumes: "dog food"
    },
    {
      type: "plant"
      name: "cactus"
      environment: "desert"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note the `animal` and `plant` types have some different properties and some shared properties.

How would `JSONDecoder` be used in Swift to convert these into the following structs:

```
struct Animal: Decodable {
  let name: String
  let consumes: String
}

struct Plant: Decodable {
  let name: String
  let environment: String
}
```

Comment: The structure is too dynamic to take advantage of `Decodable`. I recommend to use traditional `JSONSerialization`

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/44441223/2976878

Answer (score 1):

You can change your structs a bit, like this

```
enum ItemType {
    case animal(consumes: String)
    case plant(environment: String)
    case unknown
}

struct Item: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let type: ItemType

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case name
        case type
        case consumes
        case environment
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        self.name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        let type = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .type)
        switch type {
        case "animal":
            let food = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .consumes)
            self.type = .animal(consumes: food)
        case "plant":
            let environment = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .environment)
            self.type = .plant(environment: environment)
        default:
            self.type = .unknown
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting... besides the OP's question, how would one encode this particular example? I actually haven't needed to play around with custom decoder / encoder stuff yet so just curious.

Comment: While this is a good idea, it doesn't allow us to have two separate structs called `Plant` and `Animal`. It would be good if there was some way to have an array of enums where the entire struct is stored in each case. Like so: `enum Organism { case animal(Animal), case plant(Plant) }`

Answer (score -1):

Try to make consistent array structure

```
{
  data: {
animals:[
     {
         type: "animal"
         name: "Cat"
         consumes: "cat food"
    },
    {
         type: "animal"
         name: "dog"
         consumes: "dog food"
    }
],
plants:[
   {
         type: "plant"
         name: "cactus"
         environment: "desert"
    },
   {
         type: "plant"
         name: "Plam"
         environment: "hill"
    }
]


  }
}
```

Comment: I'm asking this question because I can't change the JSON API response, so we need to assume with the example I've given that it can't be changed.

Comment: Then you should go for the traditional JSON serialization or you could create a parent model to handle this.